# saving an object value passed by function

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, object

I have the folliwing code:

```
class LogFactory < ActiveRecord::Base
   after_initialize :inizializza
   MESSAGENOTDEFINED = "Msg"


   def inizializza
      self.happened = Time.current
      self.messaggio = MESSAGENOTDEFINED
   end  


    def setMessage(messaggio)
        logger = LogFactory.new(:messaggio => messaggio, :happened => self.happened)
        logger.save
    end
   end
```

The problem is in the `messaggio` variable. I mean, even if i use the param messaggio in the `.new(:messaggio => messaggio,..` rails still use the `MESSAGENOTDEFINED` constant defined during the initialization.
Why?

Comment: I think you are very confused. Can you explain with words what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cause you assign `MESSAGENOTDEFINED` to `messaggio` after object initialization. When you do something like `.new(:messaggio => 'my_messaggio', ...)`, there are 2 steps:

1. Initialization. On this step `messaggio` will assign with `'my_messagio'`.
2. `after_initialize` callback executing. On this step `messaggio` will assign with `MESSAGENOTDEFINED` anyway, according to your code.

It looks like you want use something like this:

```
def inizializza
  happened ||= Time.current
  messaggio ||= MESSAGENOTDEFINED
end
```

This means that `MESSAGENOTDEFINED` will assign to `messaggio` only if it falsey or has not initialized yet. Also, both `self` are redundant.